# Nodes are being posted but relationship Types b/w nodes are not being posted into neo4j sandbox through rest calls,

Tags: neo4j

I am using rest call to post nodes, relationship types into online neo4j sandbox, The nodes are being posted but not relations. With neo4j desktop-based tool, I'm able to post both nodes, relationship b/w nodes into the desktop tool through rest calls. With the sandbox based tool for some reason relationship types are not being posted

[sandbox lineage image in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rLBF.png)

[desktop neo4j lineage in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp7qJ.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific ? You're question is unclear so we can't help you !!

Comment: Hi, I am using rest call to post nodes, relationship types into online neo4j sandbox, The nodes are being posted but not relations. With neo4j desktop-based tool, I'm able to post both nodes, relationship b/w nodes into the desktop tool through rest calls. With the sandbox based tool for some reason relationship types are not being posted

Comment: Can you update your question instead of adding a comment ? Moreover if you have some piece of code to show it's better

Comment: I'm just passing args to already coded rest calls, nodes were posted but not relations b/w them. The first time i ran the code both nodes, relationships were posted, later onwards relationships are not being posted. Any config in sandbox that i might have missed?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the the code that is making the REST calls? It is impossible to tell what you are actually doing otherwise.

Comment: Also, are you using the same neo4j browser environment to view all results?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing the same query :

- `MATCH p=()-->() RETURN p` :  you return a path, and path is an array of node, rel, node, ...
- `MATCH (n) RETURN n` : you just return nodes

If you do the first query on both env, you should have the same result.

Otherwise, on the browser configuration (the cog on the bottom left) there is the option `Connect result nodes`, that search all relationships between nodes of your query. So perhaps you haven't the same configuration on both env.

Comment: Hey, on the left side panel in neo4j sandbox  it shows me Node Labels, Relationship tabs rt, there in the node labels tab, the nodes are posted through rest call, but relationship b/w nodes is not being posted, in the desktop tool relationship is also being posted. I can write a query if relationship b/w nodes is also imported to tool but only nodes are imported not the relationships

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. the post relation url is http://www.server.com:portno/db/data/node/id/relationships.
But in the code, it was java code it  was like http://www.server.com:portno/node/id/relationships

For some reason when triggering the rest call through java code it worked for local neo4j desktop. But for neo4j sandbox, it was showing rightly error.
Thanks